# Transformation using regex

Tags: regex, regexp-replace

I am beginner in regex, I have a list of urls such as

```
https://example.com/chicago/A2033476-city-code/
https://example.com/chicago/A3033576-city-code-data/
https://example.com/toronto/A3033876-city-code-data/
```

I am trying to write the regex which can match /chicago and the string code like A2033476. I was able to write this regex `/chicago/.*-.*`.

But i want these urls to be transformed to :

```
https://example.com/chicago/A2033476
https://example.com/chicago/A3033576
```

I want to retain the code mentioned in original URLs but right now not able to retain them. Any help will be appreciated here.

Comment: Replace `(/chicago/[^-\s]*).*` (or `(/chicago/[^-\\s]*).*`, `(/chicago/[^-[:space:]]*).*`) with `$1` (or `\1`, `\\1`,  depending on the programming environment) (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/SmpFmJ/1)).

Answer (score 1):

> 'So if you want the URLs you mentioned city name like Chicago and Toronto and the code in last here is the code for that.
> You can use the look behind for this.'

`regex = '(https://example.com/\w*/\w*)(?=-\w*) Here ?= is for look ahead  and ?<= is for look behind.`

you can ask if you will have further problem.